# How do I repeat an Alarm in Android?

Tags: android

I need to Repeat the Alarm everyday . And this is how I trigger an Alarm single time.

```
public void clicker (View view)
{

    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddAlarm.this,new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
    {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                      int selectedHour, int selectedMinute)
                {


                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

                    int c_hour,c_min;
                    String format;
                    c_hour=selectedHour;
                    c_min=selectedMinute;

                    if (c_hour == 0) {
                        c_hour += 12;
                        format = "AM";
                    } else if (c_hour == 12) {
                        format = "PM";
                    } else if (c_hour > 12) {
                        c_hour -= 12;
                        format = "PM";
                    } else {
                        format = "AM";
                    }

                    String formatTime = String.format("%02d : %02d %s", c_hour, c_min, format);

                    TextView dimple = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                    dimple.setText(formatTime);
                    setAlarm(calendar);

                }

    }, hour, minute, false);
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();



}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{
    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("ALARM_NO", tempx);
    alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

Now how should I change my code to trigger the alarm repeatedly everyday? And how can I kill the Alarm as well? Thanks ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager.setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method instead of `AlarmManager.setExact()`.

eg:

```
 // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) you can find more details for how to schedule a repeating alarm and how to **cancel** it.

Answer (score 0):

To make alarm repeat use `alarmManager.setRepeating()`
eg:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);

      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
               AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
               calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
               alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 12, pendingIntent); // format : nanosec*sec*min*hr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **wake up** the phone you cannot use `alarmManager.setRepeating()`, because it will not [wake up](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) the phone from API 19. You have to create the alarm again every time. 
This is how I create the event:

```
PendingIntent i =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmIntent, 0);
TimePickerDialog tp = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // set the TexView's text.
                    ((TextView) v).setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
                    // cancel previous alarm
                    manager.cancel(i);
                    // set alarm if the time is not 00:00
                    if(hourOfDay != 0 || minute != 0) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        // if the time is before now then add one day to it
                        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()<System.currentTimeMillis())
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis()+86400000);
                        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), i);
                    }
                }
            }, 12, 0, true);
            tp.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.time_picker_title));
            tp.show();
```

and this is how I set it again every time, I've tested it and it works well.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//Setting up the next notification
        PendingIntent alarmPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                                new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 86400000; //one day
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + interval, alarmPIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "Next alarm set to one day after now");
    }
}
```

you can do whatever you want when you receive the alarm, just you have to add the receiver also to your manifest file's aplication tag: `<receiver android:name="hu.bendaf.vivago.datatransmission.communication.AlarmReceiver"/>`
That's it.